# Simulating jack in the box(physics and lua)

Tags: lua, physics

```
function jackInTheBox(time) 
 y = amplitude * math.cos(frequency * time * 2 * math.pi) / math.exp(decay * time)  
return y end
```

Above function is to simulate how jack in the box  (When you open a jack-in-the-box, the spring-loaded “Jack” springs out with full force, and then bobs more slowly over time, until it stops. We can simulate a jack-in-the-box with the help of a little bit of trigonometry. )
But for what reason we are using cosine wave to calculate that? I always am confused about the fact if sine is to be used or cosine. Is the only reason after it that jack swings right and left with certain speed along the x-axis? Or anything more than that?

Comment: With `cos` y(0)==amplitude, y(inf)==0.  With `sin` y(0)==y(inf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sine is identical to a cosine translated by pi/2 radians. In other words, they only differ by a phase of pi/2. So it doesnt matter which function you use, except that the phase is determined by the initial condition: at t=0, the spring is at y=y0 (normally the speed is zero but this is not required). From this you determine the phase, although if the speed is 0 you know the spring must be at a crest. If you pick sine, sine a*t at t=0 is 0 so you need a phase of pi/2. If you pick a cosine, the t=0 already is at crest of function so phase is zero.

There is no relationship between function used and the sideways motion which is caused by combination of initial non-zero angle of spring to vertical, gravity which exerts torque on spring CofM, and possibly uneven vertical compression across the cross section of spring which causes some bending and thus couples the compression with horizontal CofM motion.

To summarize, you could have used either one but using cosine leads to a simpler equation given the initial conditions. Other initial conditions could have resulted in sine leafing to simpler equation and yet others to either function being similar complexity.